# Conceitos para a adoção da orientação a objeto

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, teoria-da-computação

Me deparei com esta pergunta, pesquisei e a resposta correta é:

> e) a computação seja acionada por troca de mensagens entre objetos.

Concordo que a **E** é verdadeira, mas o que eu não entendo é o seguinte, porque a letra **D** esta errada?

> A orientação a objetos é uma forma abstrata de pensar um problema utilizando-se conceitos do mundo real e não, apenas, conceitos computacionais. Nessa perspectiva, a adoção do paradigma orientado a objetos implica necessariamente que:
>
> - a) os usuários utilizem as aplicações de forma mais simples.
> - b) os sistemas sejam encapsulados por outros sistemas.
> - c) os programadores de aplicações sejam mais especializados.
> - d) os objetos sejam implementados de maneira eficiente e simples.
> - e) a computação seja acionada por troca de mensagens entre objetos.

Pelo o que eu entendo sobre orientação a objeto a **D** esta correta também.

Comment: A **D** para mim parece errada. Posso implementar algo usando a orientação a objetos sem ser eficiente, ou então adicionar níveis de complexidade desnecessários para algo simples de se fazer

Comment: Acredito que esta D esteja mais voltada a boas práticas com OO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao meu ver, as palavras chaves aqui são ***implicam necessariamente***. Por mais que simplicidade geralmente está presente na filosofia para a implementação dos conceitos de orientação a objetos, não é um quesito necessário para ser configurado como tal. Eu posso aplicar os conceitos de orientação a objetos de forma a complexar minha aplicação sem necessidade e mesmo assim será orientação a objetos.

Um exemplo simplório seria a criação de uma classe que representa o usuário do sistema. De forma simples, eu poderia fazer algo como:

```
class User {
    public string name { get; set };
    public string username { get; set };
    public string password { get; set; };
}
```

Dependendo da aplicação, essa classe já seria suficiente, porém é possível deixá-la mais complexa, por exemplo, utilizando o conceito de herança. Podemos imaginar que `username` e `password` são características do usuário, mas `name` é uma característica de uma pessoa; assim, seria possível criar uma classe `Person` e a classe `User` herdar dela:

```
class Person {
    public string name { get; set };
}

class User extends Person {
    public string username { get; set };
    public string password { get; set; };
}
```

Foi aplicado um conceito trivial de orientação a objeto, mas isso não implica que minha aplicação ficou mais eficiente ou mais simples. Pode acontecer inclusive o contrário: mais pesada e muito mais complexa.